# X-raid logical failure

Tags: raid

Our ReadyNAS X-raid (4* 1.5TB) have some logical errors.

I gave it to a recovery company, and they want 3500 USD to recover the data.

Why is it so expensive?
If I have no physical problems, can I recover the data with some software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SvenW already pointed out, it really depends on what kind of error you're running into... if you could be more specific with what you mean with "logical errors" and what kind of ReadyNAS (NV, NV+, NVX, DUO, Pro, etc....) you have maybe some help would be possible.

X-raid is basically an extended version of LVM2 so usually you can just insert the disks in any Linux system with the necessary packages installed but depending on what kind of ReadyNAS you own you might run into problems with blocksizes (NV+ can use blocksizes of up to 16k, FS drivers in Linux kernels on x86/AMD64 machines only support blocksizes up to 4k).

The ReadyNAS forums (http://www.readynas.com/forum/) might also be a good source for information as many people there already asked similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe. Maybe not. It totally depends on the kind of error. But since you have to ask this question, I would recommend not to try it because chances are high you will create an even bigger damage.

Why do they charge so much?

- First reason: Because they can. You neglected to do proper backups and are now in an emergency and have to pay the price for it.
- Second reason: They have to maintain a really expensive environment with clean rooms, equipment and a large inventory of hard disk spare parts etc. and last but not least, data recovery specialists usually have relatively high salaries. This means proper data recovery **is** expensive.

Comment: I agree with both of your comments. Still, is there a software tool? I am sure someone has wrote an open source to do it.